# How to tap / click at x,y position automatically?

Tags: android, button, automation, click

I have created one `AlertDialog` with OK and CANCEL button's in my application, when ever that alert dialog opened. i have to tap/click on OK button automatically without user interaction, i have x,y position of OK button.

How to implement this please share with me, My main requirement is how to tap at particular position (x, y) automatically with out user interaction .

Comment: here, i am not asking .. how to close dialog ?... i need  how to run some function to trigger when ok button tap. ?

Comment: Are you writing a unit test case?

Comment: @Mike here i want to trigger only  OK button always.. automatically.

Comment: @zIronManBox yes... i am creating some test cases.. that should run automatically with out user interaction.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Which android Unit Test lib are you using?

Comment: @zIronManBox.... i am not using any existing one .... i am creating only some task related to my application

Comment: @MikeM. i don't know the components what are available in that dialog. and it may vary depends on the requirement. My main concern is how to tap at particular position (x, y) automatically.

Comment: I am using some native alert dialog.. not customized alert dialog. this is like i  am not creating anything like buttons.. this alert dialog may be some other applications alert dialog also..like Facebook permissions accept and reject dialog. like that.. i want to inject tap at x, y position on that dialog/ scree,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `performClick()` method. See the [View docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) for reference.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewByid(R.id.mybutton);
button.performClick();
```

Or, if developing for Ice Cream Sandwich (API Level 15), the `callOnClick()` method was added. `performClick()` is more than suitable for your needs, though.

For a Alert Dialog interface positive button, you can use: as Suggested by @Mike

```
dialogToClick.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();.
```

Comment: If that dialog not from my application .. i mean opened dialog from other application. like facebook interaction with my app.. how can i get those Positive button and tap on that positive button.

Comment: You can't access functionalities or features of other app unless you have the permission to. This will be basically hacking into the app, which you could do if you have rooted android.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Write a new query

Comment: Ok. i will write new query regarding that... i have accepted this as answer and.. please up vote to question ..